# pleasure derived from time in nature

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means pleasure derived from nature?

I'm working on an assignment where I need to identify my personal values. So I started by thinking about the non-material things that mean the most to me. I found myself thinking about was how nature makes me feel.

Have you ever been on a hike or camping trip and you have an overwhelming sense of happiness or comfort from being completely separated from man-made materials such as buildings, streets, technology, etc.?  I found a list of values that includes "nature" but I feel as if valuing nature and valuing the pleasure gained from being immersed *in* nature are two different values and concepts. One who values nature seems to have the connotation of preservation and conservation and while I personally value nature, I would also like to include a term with the sensation I have described that is brought from being outdoors.

An example of how this word would be used could be "I like to visit mountains because it gives me the feeling of ____, reminding me of other trips and times I have been away from all things man-made"

Comment: What is a word that means pleasure derived from nature?

Comment: The words I can think of -- oneness, connectivity -- don't directly mention nature but tend to happen in the countryside when no one else is around.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single word or anything *specific*, but the idiom [**at one with**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20one%20with) (*nature*) applies:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : in a peaceful state as a part of something else
>   // I feel *at one with* nature.

So:

> I like to visit mountains because it gives me the feeling of being ***at one with*** *nature*, reminding me of other trips and times I have been away from all things man-made.

Comment: Don't know who or why someone downvoted, but, +1

Answer (score 0):

**Naturophilia** would be a specific word for the meaning but it wouldn't sound "natural" in your example. It is from Latin *nātūra* + *-philia* suffix.

The term is not in the big dictionaries but it naturally occurred to me. Then I've checked in Google also and it's been used quite a lot. *Philia-words* are usually coined for a specific need or meaning.

Here are some good definitions I've found (which come down to love of nature, feeling better in nature, feeling connected to nature):

From *[Entrepreneurship in culture and creative industries: Perspectives from companies and regions](https://books.google.ca/books?id=W6I7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA267&dq=naturophilia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM0qDbgoToAhWwiOAKHYidDDwQ6AEISzAF#v=onepage&q=naturophilia&f=false)* (edited by Elisa Innerhofer, Harald Pechlaner, Elena Borin):

> Rural tourism is constructed upon a collective imagery of naturophilia, the idea that the rural environment provides quality and authenticity and offers a romantic outlook, as opposed to the life within a bustling city (Pearce 1990). The return to nature as a way to escape from the pressure of city life is a widespread idea present in our societies.

From a Naturophilia Exhibition in Melbourne:

> [image]
>
> naturophilia: the state or experience of a strong attraction or affinity to nature; nature loving
>
> naturophilic: to possess qualities that allow the ready absorption of or the dissolution into nature
>
> <sub>https://www.weekendnotes.com/naturophilia-exhibition-carlton-connect/</sub>

---

**Connectedness** is a more common but less specific word that would fit in your example sentence. It is usually used for human-nature connection in a relevant context.

From *[The Oxford Textbook of Nature and Public Health](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Oxford_Textbook_of_Nature_and_Public_Hea.html?id=pAJCDwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)* (edited by Matilda van den Bosch, William Bird):

> Being attached to natural environments and even having a feeling of connectedness to nature may provide an existential sense of well-being (Bonaiuto and Alves, 2012).

Comment: Until it appears in a respected dictionary or can be otherwise shown to have a reasonably broad usage, a candidate must be considered not to have been worded. A Google Ngram for your candidate flatlines, and although there are examples on the internet, it seems difficult to find one that is not capitalised.